# Reorder rows in sqlite3 database

Tags: sqlite

**TL;DR**
I want to create a copy of a table but where the rows are sorted against an arbitrary column.

Say I create `table0` that way:

```sql
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE table0 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT);
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table0(col1, col2) VALUES('a', 'z');
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table0(col1, col2) VALUES('b', 'y');
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table0(col1, col2) VALUES('c', 'x');
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM table0;
    1|a|z
    2|b|y
    3|c|x
```

I want the copy ordered against `col2`. Hence the copy should look like this:

```sql
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM copy;
    1|c|x
    2|b|y
    3|a|z
```

**FAILING ATTEMPTS**

I've tried to create a `table1` the same way as I created `table0`, and then use `ORDER BY`, but I end up with the exact same content as `table0`:

```sql
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT);
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table0 ORDER BY col2;
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1;
    1|a|z
    2|b|y
    3|c|x
```

Then I tried to create the copy in another way, and it works a little bit better:

```sql
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table0 WHERE 0;
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table0 ORDER BY col2;
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM table2;
    3|c|x
    2|b|y
    1|a|z
```

But the first column isn't correct. I need it as described at the start of my question.

Of course I could enter the rows manually in the right order, yet it wouldn't work using the second way of create the copied table (the primary key is missing...):

```sql
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT * FROM table0 WHERE 0;
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table3(col1, col2) VALUES('c', 'x');
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table3(col1, col2) VALUES('b', 'y');
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table3(col1, col2) VALUES('a', 'z');
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM table3;
    |c|x
    |b|y
    |a|z
```

So the only successful way consists of reproducing the exact same commands as for `table0`, just changing the order:

```sql
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE table4 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT);
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table4(col1, col2) VALUES('c', 'x');
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table4(col1, col2) VALUES('b', 'y');
    sqlite> INSERT INTO table4(col1, col2) VALUES('a', 'z');
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM table4;
    1|c|x
    2|b|y
    3|a|z
```

How to automate this, to not have to make it manually on a more important number of rows?

This will be programmed with python, if that's of any relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are unordered sets.
If what you want is to have the `id` column of the copy table in the order of `col2` then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2), col1, col2
FROM table0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6u5fS6RXu2seFTEcLB8uDi/1).
Results:

```
| id  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 1   | c    | x    |
| 2   | b    | y    |
| 3   | a    | z    |
```

Comment: In the meanwhile I've finally found out that `INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) SELECT col1,col2 FROM table0 ORDER BY col2;` does the trick too, provided `table1` is created with the same command as `table0` (no `CREATE ... AS ...`).

Comment: You can use CREATE TABLE AS.. with ROW_NUMBER(): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6u5fS6RXu2seFTEcLB8uDi/2 but the table created will not have a primary key: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html